# Issue Connecting Stash and Jenkins with SSH

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket-server

Follow the instructions here: http://nerdwin15.com/2013/04/continuous-integration-with-stash-and-jenkins/

I Have jenkins and stash "connected" however, running the builds hangs at

> Fetching upstream changes from
>   ssh://git@git.xyz.com:7999/gp/gp-xyz.git
>
> FATAL: Failed to fetch from ssh://git@git.xyz.com:7999/gp/gp-xyz.git
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from
>   ssh://git@git.xyz.com:7999/gp/gp-xyz.git

So from what I gather the problem is that if i run this command on jenkins (which is running on windows)..

> $ git clone ssh://git@git.xyz.com:7999/gp/gp-xyz.git Cloning into
>   'gp-xyz'... Enter passphrase for key '/c/Documents and
>   Settings/userMe/.ssh/id_rsa':

Is the fact that I have to enter a password here. How can i configure windows to store the ssh key so that I can clone like the build server does?

What i tried is:

> userMe@jenkins /C $ ssh -T git@git.xyz.com:7999 ssh:
>   git.xyz.com:7999: no address associated with name
>
> userMe@jenkins /C $ ssh -T git@git.xyz.com git@git.xyz.com's
>   password: Permission denied, please try again. git@git.xyz.com's
>   password:

However, This confuses me. Because Stash is running on port 7999 and there is no actual user named git on stash but it wont let me change that?

Answer (score 1):

Use open ssh to setup private and public keys on your windows host

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use a service like open SSH to generate a DSA/RSA-2 key and setup a no_pw option. (Do not setup an RSA-1 key) as stash has issues with RSA-1.
2. After that , add your public key into your list of keys in your stash user profile.

Regarding your other questions,

1. By default, Stash http protocol runs on port 7990 and the ssh protocol is supported on protocol 7999.
2. git is a default userid used by Stash behind the scenes to talk to the underlying git repository